# Inserting data doesn't replicate into database

Tags: c#, .net, t-sql, ado.net, sql-server-ce

I have a written a sample code to insert data into a table and it says successfully inserted, but when I see the data in database in the database explorer, table shows nothing.

When I try to retrieve the data, it prints those values. Still I don't find any records in Visual Studio server explorer.

I have tried to google this problem, and I found another database in debug folder which replicates those results.

When I delete that database, I'm stuck with a "connection failed" error.

this is sample code:

```
DomainId_connection = openConnection();

cmd = new SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO Temp_Table_(Id,StartTime) values(@Id ,@StartTime)");

cmd.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.Int, 4);
setDomainId_cmd.Parameters.Add("@StartTime", SqlDbType.DateTime, 8);

cmd.Parameters["@Id"].Value = Id;
cmd.Parameters["@StartTime"].Value = DateTime.Now;

cmd.Connection = setDomainId_connection;
if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Domain id stored");
}

closeConnection(setDomainId_connection);
```

Can someone help me making this work?

Comment: Willing to share some code or potential answerers to your question should rely on their telepathic skills?

Comment: Try to follow this example http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Esempio-applicazione-dati-70387089 Regards

Comment: You're using 2 different connection objects: `DomainId_connection`, `setDomainId_connection` and 2 different command objects: `cmd`, `setDomainId_cmd`. Clean up this mess.

Comment: i have pasted the wrong code, but i have used only one connection string and one command object

Comment: @rockyit86: Please edit it to remove the ambiguity

Answer (score 2):

Don't share connection, use connection pooling, use using blocks, and many more:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    command.CommandText = commandText;

    command.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.Int, 4).Value = id;
    command.Parameters.Add("@StartTime", SqlDbType.DateTime, 8).Value =  DateTime.Now;

   if (!(cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0))
       throw new Exception("Domain id was not stored");
}
```

Comment: That looks a lot better but i think the problem is with his connections string pointing to a wrong database.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the connection string to point to your other database which is used in the server Explorer.

Comment: Unless you establish a connection how can you insert the data, my problem is to how to view the data and why i have another database in debug folder, if i change the properties for the database to not copy the output then i dont find any changes in any databases .I either in debug folder nor the actual one.I have even checked with the connection string it points to database which in projects folder not in debug folder.....

Comment: @rockyit86: What is your connection string?

Comment: I'm guessing you get the connection string from the app.config, you could take a look at the app.config in your debug folder maybe it is changed in the build process somehow.

Comment: I hope it will and you should consider the answer form @abatishchev to refactor your code so it will be readable and better understandable and you can work with it easier in the future.